# error when connecting mysql to Java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I am trying to connect a `connector/j driver` to *Netbeans*.

I am following below steps to connect,

1. In services I  right click and click new connection.
2. then I  browse and add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` file .
3. Then click next.
4. Then comes a `JDBC url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql` is
   showing.
5. I click the **test connection button**

Then I get the following error:

> Cannot establish a connection
>   to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql using com.mysql.jdbc.
>   Driver (Communications link failure
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
>   The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

Comment: Is MySQL running on your machine?

Comment: Corrected grammar, simplified formatting

Comment: @JohnHascall MySQL is working in my machine

Comment: How would you solve this problem I am in the same case.

Comment: try eclipse......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally had this problem too. Netbeans sometimes has problems dealing with MySQL. I would suggest you download MySQL Community Server and MySQL Workbench and use those to run your database. It's much more efficient and gives you more control over your database.

Comment: thanks for your reply it is working

Comment: I also in same problem but I can connect using the workbench and mysql administrator. But mysql connection using netbeans is faild and It is same for the compiled and maked EXE files 
I am using windows 10 OS 
 [![enter image [![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jlw4.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUCx3.png

Answer (score 0):

I get this types of error and I have fixed as follows 
first open `/etc/my.cnf` file and comment

```
# skip-networking
```

and check where is bind-adress if not add the following

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
bind-address            = your ip address
```