# Can not connect to database service in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to connect to database that is embedded in NetBeans using this driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar(It was preinstalled). However, when I try to do this all I get is this error:

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

I've googled it and found this: [error when connecting mysql to Java netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938331/error-when-connecting-mysql-to-java-netbeans)

There is one solution with editing my.cnf file which I do not know where to find. **I use Windows 10 OS and have no idea where etc/my.cnf file can be.**

Comment: @mark-rotteveel I've written there that I also do not know where is this file my.cnf.

Comment: See extra duplicate I added, and the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html